# TFS 2010:sprint backlog item is not visible in workitem menu

Tags: tfs, tfs-process-template, tfs-2010

I installed TFS 2010 trial version. 
In Visual studio editor, under Team menu->New Work Item,
I found only Bug, Issue, Shared Steps, Task, Testcase, User Story
I didn't find ChangeRequest, Review, Risk, Sprint Backlog Items.
How can I get those in my Team menu;
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your project was created using a CMMI process template. If you have nothing yet in it, the easiest way would be to create a new TeamProject using a SCRUM Template.

If you already worked with the project, you could install the TFS Power Tools. In VS you will get the Tools menu entry "Process Editor" -> "Work Item Types" -> "Import WIT"
Now you need the XML files which define the work items you need. If you have other projects using these types, you can use "Export WIT" there and Import them in your project. If you don't have them there, you need to download them. Possible locations:

```
◦Scrum for Team System version 3 (on TFS 2010) 
https://www.scrumforteamsystem.com/Products/Search/SfTS%20v3 

◦MSF Agile version 5 (on TFS 2010) 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380647.aspx 


◦Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 1.0 (on TFS 2010) 
 http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e
```